# Finding partition key for stateful service in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I've followed the steps here to create a reverse proxy on my resource group in Azure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy

I believe the reverse proxy is working because I used to receive a 404 error, now I am receiving a 400 Bad Request.

The error code is FABRIC_E_INVALID_PARTITION_KEY

This kind of makes sense, because in the documentation, it says for services not using the singleton partition, you must specify a partition key and partition kind, like this:

```
http://mycluster.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:19008/MyApp/MyService?PartitionKey=3&PartitionKind=Int64Range
```

My question is, how do I get that partition key? The documentation explicitly states it is not the GUID generated in the explorer, so I can't use that. I am contacting this stateful service from an external application, outside of the fabric.

Answer (score 13):

The `PartitionId` you see in the Service Explorer is the unique id of the Partition that your service request ends up on. The `PartitionKey` is not the same as the `PartitionId`, it is rather the the key that goes into the Partitioning Hash and based on that the partition that a request with that key ends up on is calculated from.

In the `ApplicationManifest.xml` in the Application project the partitioning key for a newly created service looks like this:

```
<Service Name="MyService">
  <StatefulService ServiceTypeName="MyServiceType" 
                   TargetReplicaSetSize="[MyService_TargetReplicaSetSize]"
                   MinReplicaSetSize="[MyService_MinReplicaSetSize]">
    <UniformInt64Partition PartitionCount="[MyService_PartitionCount]"
                           LowKey="-9223372036854775808"
                           HighKey="9223372036854775807" />
  </StatefulService>
</Service>
```

Here the `UniformInt64Partition` indicates that it is an `Int64Range` that is used. The `LowKey` and `HighKey` gives the range of accepted PartitionKeys. The `PartitionCount` gives the number of partitions that runs this service. In the uniform range then the partitions are uniformly mapped from low to high keys. You should probably change the range to something that makes more sense for your specifik service. E.g.:

```
  <Parameters>
      ...
      <Parameter Name="MyService_PartitionCount" DefaultValue="2" />
      ...
  </Parameters>
  ...
<Service Name="MyService">
  <StatefulService ServiceTypeName="MyServiceType" 
                   TargetReplicaSetSize="[MyService_TargetReplicaSetSize]"
                   MinReplicaSetSize="[MyService_MinReplicaSetSize]">
    <UniformInt64Partition PartitionCount="[MyService_PartitionCount]"
                           LowKey="0"
                           HighKey="11" />
  </StatefulService>
</Service>
```

This would give us **2** partitions that are mapped:

- 0 - 5: Partition 0
- 6 - 11: Partition 1

Having a partition range that is greater than the number of partitions is integral in allowing us to scale out later on without having to change our partition keys. If we in the example above double the number of partitions (scale out) to **4** partitions then the mapping would become:

- 0 - 2: Partition 0
- 3 - 5: Partition 1
- 6 - 8: Partition 2
- 9 - 11: Partition 3

The partition keys we use would however not change, meaning that clients of the service are not affected. Similar reasoning goes for Named scheme. The other possible scheme is Singleton and that one is usually used for Stateless services.

Microsoft's documentation on partitioning for services can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-partitioning

Back to your question, your partition key could be any integer within the range LowKey and HighKey as you have specified in your manifest (if you use the `UniformInt64Partition`). That you get the `FABRIC_E_INVALID_PARTITION_KEY` error is indicating that the provided key is not a valid integer. If it were outside the accepted range you would likely get `FABRIC_E_KEY_NOT_FOUND` as an error instead.

Comment: Is there a way to get this information at runtime? -- e.g. a call that we can make that will return to us the partition metadata, which we can then inspect to find out that, indeed, partition 0 has a range of 0 - 2, partition 1 has a range of 3 - 5, etc.? -- I would hate to have to hard code something like this.

Comment: Yes, you can use [FabricClient.QueryManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.querymanager?view=servicefabric-5.5.216#System_Fabric_FabricClient_QueryManager) to query the partitions of a specific service. Depending on the partitioning scheme (int64, named or singleton) you will get a result of ServicePartitionInformation that will give you the span (low key - high key) or value for each partition. This [gist](https://gist.github.com/FredrikGoransson/846935fcfef0c1d19980402875c1b511) shows how to retrieve it from inside an SF service.

Comment: Partition count can't change in the run time. If you want change the partition count, you need redeploy, but in this case, all state will be lost.

Comment: Yes, changing the partitioning of a service is a complex operation and not supported explicitly by SF services. You need to repartition and move your state manually. As James states, you cannot change it in run time, but I still find it a good practice to decouple your code a little from the actual partitioning of a service as it may very well be different in different environments (eg test vs prod)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the partitioning type you choose.

- For named partitions, you just provide the name.
- For Int64RangePartitions, you provide an Int64 that's between the
  target partitions' Higkey and Lowkey value. (inclusive)

To find it:

In the SF explorer, navigate to a stateful service, and select a partition. On the 'Essentials' tab it shows the partition kind and the key(s).

The downside of using the built in reverse proxy is exactly this situation you're in. Detailed knowledge of service partitioning is required at the caller. This is why I chose to use a custom stateless service as a proxy, and route calls based on context myself. (for instance, a hash of the tenant/user id could lead to an int64 partition key)

Comment: Exactly my issue. I created a stateless service, and if I try to access it ...com:19008/MyApp/MyService I get a FABRIC_E_INVALID_ADDRESS 400 response.

Comment: That's a different error. But judging by your new question you seem to have fixed it? (maybe missing the path to the controller action) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580204/connecting-an-nservicebus-gateway-on-an-azure-service-fabric-stateless-service

Comment: Ok, I can see these crazy partition ranges now -- but something tells me these are dynamic. -- Is there a way to programatically enumerate the partitions, and find out what their ranges are?

Comment: They are definitely not dynamic. Each partition holds a shard of your data. That shard needs to have a well defined scope. Here's how to list partitions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38562986/5946937