# Service Fabric application instance configuration

Tags: .net, web-services, azure-service-fabric

How do you configure different application *instances*?  I know you can parameterize the `ApplicationManifest` and service `Config` packages, but how would you specify a different port for the webservice in two different application instances?  The endpoint for the webservice is defined in the `ServiceManifest`, which can not be parameterized afaik.

```html
<Resources>
  <Endpoints>
    <!-- This endpoint is used by the communication listener to obtain the port on which to 
           listen. Please note that if your service is partitioned, this port is shared with 
           replicas of different partitions that are placed in your code. -->
    <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="80" />
  </Endpoints>
</Resources>
```

Say I have an Application Type `MyAppType` which contains  a service type `MyWebSvcType`.  I create two instances of the application type `MyAppTenant1` and `MyAppTenant2`.  How do I specify that the webservice of `MyAppTenant1` listens on port 80 and the webservice of `MyAppTenant2` listens on port 81.  This is because they could be on the same node, and thus should listen to different ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you omit the Port attribute, your service instance will get a dynamic port assigned. You can find the service endpoints by using [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518214/how-can-i-dynamically-discover-services-hosted-in-service-fabric-from-api-manage) or you can access it through the built in reverse proxy.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-manifest-resources) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services).

Comment: I tried your suggestion for using the Reverse Proxy.  However, it seems to always send my requests to the first application instance, no matter the application name I put in the URL, like 'http://mycluster:19008/PartitionTestGreen/WebSvc/api/Values/10' still sends me to the PartitionTestYellow application instance instead of the PartitionTestGreen instance.

Comment: I don't have to configure anything on the reverse proxy itself?  It is enabled (shows in the portal as enabled) and it clearly forwards requests for all application instances, but only to the wrong instance (always the same).

Comment: I haven't experienced that problem myself, it works fine for me. No additional configuration is required. Can you run the code snippet that lists endpoints, to see if all endpoints are as you'd expect them to be?