# Get the port assigned to the current service in Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

If you make a new Service Fabric Web Api application the `PackageRoot/ServiceManifest.xml` file has a `ServiceManifest/Resource/Endpoints/Endpoint` node with the attribute `Port`.   Service Fabric uses this to decide the port to host the service on.

But if you delete this attribute, then Service Fabric will dynamically pick a port for you.

**I am trying to find a way to get what that port is while the application is running.**

I know I could ask the Service Fabric API for a list of the Endpoints for my service and then limit that down by my current node.  And that is very close.  But if for some reason my service is hosted twice on the same node, then I will not be able to know which one is the "Current" application.

I am hoping there is a way that does not involve a service call to the cluster.

Is the port that is selected stored somewhere that I can access it.  (In the `StatefulServiceContext` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a way to get this value.  It seems as if service fabric adds a bunch of environment variables for the executing process.  One of them has the port in it.

This code gave me my port number:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FABRIC_ENDPOINT_SERVICEENDPOINT")
```

And important thing to note is that the value you use as the environment variable lookup string is dependent on your application's configuration.

The first part (FABRIC_ENDPOINT_) is always the same.

But the rest depends on the value in the config file I mentioned in the question (ServiceManifest.xml).  It must match what is in the `ServiceManifest/Resource/Endpoints/Endpoint` Name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple instances of the same service (replica) running on the same node in 1 application. So filter the API query `GetApplicationListAsync` by current Application name, using code similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38562986/5946937). You can get the current application name from the `ServiceContext`.

Comment: Are you sure you can't have more than one of the same service running in one node?  I think that, at least for stateless services, you can.  In fact the Dev Server hosts 5 on the same node.  And the Service Fabric blog has a post about Citrix hosting 100 instances of their identity service on 10 nodes: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/12/08/service-fabric-customer-profile-citrix/