# Set up Azure Front Door healthcheck with microservices

Tags: microservices, azure-service-fabric, azure-front-door

I have a service fabric cluster with multiple microservices, and I want to set up Azure Front Door, however it asks for a healthcheck endpoint in the backend but I don't know how I am supposed to set it up since the cluster doesn't have an endpoint for that.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a health check on your service, by introducing a [watchdog service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/service-fabric-watchdog-service/service-fabric-watchdog-service/). Optionally tapping into the [built-in health system](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-overview) of SF. It could look like this:

1. Create an ASP .NET Core Web API, and implement some health checks. For example, a custom [check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-health-checks) if your [SF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38562986/5946937) is alive (and well). [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1) how to get started. Return `200 OK` from the API, if the watched SF Service is running correctly.
2. Run this Web API as an [SF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore) Service. Expose it through the Load Balancer.
3. Use its URL as the health endpoint for your Service(s).