# Service communication in Service Fabric for Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, websocket, azure-service-fabric

There are two service types. A service A which is spread across all nodes and a service B which is deployed only on a single node. Services communicate via web-socket using C#. Service A connects to service B. The connection is intra-cluster connection because service A is a public service and service B is an internal service.

In Windows ws:// could be used because DNS resolution is available. Since Linux is used, DNS resolution is not supported (yet?). How can I get similar functionality or at least an IP of the service B
?

Answer (score 0):

You can use manual resolution using Fabric Client/ServicePartitionResolver is the available alternative.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38562986/5946937) for details

Instead of looping over all apps and services you can provide name filters directly.