# Service discovery on docker-compose Service Fabric cluster running on Linux

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have created a docker-compose cluster that I want to deploy to a Linux based SF cluster. All the apps are obviously created on docker and they talk to each other using DNS. Upon cloud development on the aforementioned Linux SF cluster, services cannot talk to each other via DNS although I have configured hostname and network aliases as shown below.

On my local machine, everything runs smooth and services can talk to each other. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

```
identity:
    image: .....
    environment:
    ...
    ports:
      - "5020:5020"
    hostname: identity.dhcloud
    networks:
       default:    
          aliases:
            - identity.dhcloud
```

Thanks,

Kind Regards,
José.

Answer (score 0):

SF DNS [doesn't work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-dnsservice#enabling-the-dns-service) (yet) in Linux Clusters.

> DNS service for Service Fabric services is not yet supported on Linux.

Only a [small subset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-docker-compose#supported-compose-directives) of docker compose operations is supported. Hostnames and aliases aren't in the list.

> - Services > Deploy > Replicas
> - Services > Deploy > Placement > Constraints
> - Services > Deploy > Resources > Limits
>
>   - cpu-shares
>   - memory
>   - memory-swap
> - Services > Commands
> - Services > Environment
> - Services > Ports
> - Services > Image
> - Services > Isolation (only for Windows)
> - Services > Logging > Driver
> - Services > Logging > Driver > Options
> - Volume & Deploy > Volume

You can use manual resolution using Fabric Client/ServicePartitionResolver is the available alternative. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38562986/5946937) for details

```
var resolver = ServicePartitionResolver.GetDefault();
var fabricClient = new FabricClient();
var services = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetServiceListAsync(applicationName);
var resolved = await resolver.ResolveAsync(services[0].ServiceName, someKey, CancellationToken.None);
```

Instead of looping over all apps and services you can provide name filters directly.